# Execution of Data spread across multiple sheets of Excel in selenium

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

We are trying to run an automation script which would pick data from sheet1 of excel in run1, then signout of application, in second run data to be picked from second sheet of excel and so on.. we are trying achieve it through data provider.

Can anyone help in achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QAF - TestNG's data-provider-extension](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/wiki/3rd-party-extensions#data-provider-extension). It supports [dynamic data-provider](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) to read data from any of external data source. For example:

```
@QAFDataProvider (dataFile = "resources/data/logintestdata.xls", sheetName="sheet-${executionNumber}")
@Test(description = "login functionality test")
public void login(Map<String, Object> testData) {
   //implementation goes here
}
```

You need to [set property](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/different_ways_of_providing_prop.html) `executionNumber`:

```
executionNumber=1
```